# For looping to add variables for a Scanner input

Tags: java, variables, for-loop, java.util.scanner

So I'm new to Java and I figured I'd do something simple like a for loop to print out an array of strings or something,
My code ended up like this:

```
package package.four;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arrayrecurse {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter 5 words");
    String a = in.next();
    String b = in.next();
    String c = in.next();
    String d = in.next();
    String e = in.next();
    String[] s = {a, b, c, d, e};
    for(int i = 0; i< s.length;){
        System.out.println(s[i]);
        i++;
    }
    in.close();
}
}
```

It works fine but my question is if it's possible to make a for loop cycle through variables.
For examples if I wanted something like:

```
for(words = 5; words > 0;){
String a = in.next();
a++}
```

Where would it change the variables each time I enter a new word.
Would it be possible to do something like that or do I need to type out the `String variable = in.next();` every time I want to enter a new word input from the console?

Answer (score 1):

Use an ArrayList to store the input variables.

That is:

```
import java.util.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> inputVars = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (sc.hasNext())
    {
        inputVars.add(sc.next());
    }

    for (String s: inputVars)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Or alternatively, if you want to change the contents of the ArrayList:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> inputVars = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (sc.hasNext())
    {
        inputVars.add(sc.next());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < inputVars.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(inputVars.get(i));            
        //Change the variable
        inputVars.set(i, "Hello, " + inputVars.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds interesting but eclipse pops an error saying neither list nor arraylist can be resolved to a type. Do I need to import something to use it or am I just making some really stupid mistake? edit: didn't expect pressing enter would send the comment.

Comment: import java.util.* at the top.

Comment: Eclipse should give you the option to automatically do the imports if you hover over the type you are missing.

Comment: Well that fixes it. Thanks. I do feel bad for asking but I don't suppose you could tell me how to actually use the variables I'm inputting as variables instead of just printing them out. When I try just changing it to String s = in.next(); it comes up with an error about multiple s variables.

Comment: That depends --- what do you want to do with your input variables?

Comment: I want to use them in place of the variables I had in my original code for the variable names of the strings I'm inputting into the array.

Comment: In your original code, you were just storing a,b,c,d,e into a regular Array.  Why do you need the array?

Comment: I was just messing around to practice my coding. The array doesn't really matter. I was really just curious about how to use a bunch of variables without needing to keep writing down variable names. So if I wanted 24 different string inputs I could just use a for or while loop to code the inputs instead of needing to type them all down.

Comment: Ah.  Well, the ArrayList is storing all your variables for you.  If you don't know how many inputs you will have, then it is best to use some sort of collection to hold the resulting variables.

Comment: Well I was just going to do for (int i = 5; i > 0;){
         inputVars.add(in.next());
         i--;
     }
I just don't know how to then get those 5 variables from the list to actually be used as variables in something like for(i=5;i>0;){String variable = in.next(); i--;}

Comment: I should mention I was just going to use a b c d e for my variable inputs in inputVars.add(in.next());

Though I just realized that if I could figure out how to manipulate the first element of a list as a variable then I could probably just have those act as variables for both the in.next(); and the array.

Comment: in.next() is already being stored in the list.  That is what the inputVars.add(...) does.

Comment: But all it  does is store whatever I enter next into the list. If I want to do something like put that into an array I can't do it. 
I wanted to store the variables in a list for future convenient usage so that I would not need to keep rewriting new variables if I wanted to add certain things to an array or use certain variables in other things in the future(like doing int a = 1; int b = 2; int c = 3; int d = 4; system.out.print(a+b/c); then system.out.print(b+c/d);
I want to be able to reuse the variables I store in the list not just have them print out.

Comment: Use the get method:   `int a = inputVars.get(0);` `int b = inputVars.get(1);`

Comment: That would just make the code even longer since I'd have to type out the inputVars.ass(sc.next()); first and it'd be shorter to just type out int a = in.nextInt(); int b = in.nextInt(); etc.
Honestly at this point I just don't think there's a quicker way of doing this.
I'd still give you heaps of rep for trying if I could though.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `next()` inside the loop, but you need to declare the variable outside the loop if you want to use it afterwards, also, there is no `++` operator for String or array in Java:

```
String[] inputs = new String[5];
for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i)
{
    inputs[i] = in.next();
}
```